# Remove clickthrough link in Media Player Framework

Tags: uwp, media-player, uwp-xaml, windows-media-player

I am using `VAST 2.0` video ads in Media Player Framework. Here, I want to remove the `clickthroughButton` link i.e. the default `Learn more...` text from the ad. I do not want the `clickthrough` hyperlink button over my ad.
Here is the media player scheduler code I am using :

```
<Page
    xmlns:my="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework"
    xmlns:ads="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework.Advertising" 
>

<my:MediaPlayer x:Name="player" Source="www.xyz.com">
    <my:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
       <ads:AdSchedulerPlugin>
           <ads:AdSchedulerPlugin.Advertisements>
                <ads:PrerollAdvertisement>
                    <ads:PrerollAdvertisement.Source>
                        <ads:RemoteAdSource Name="vastSource" Uri="abx" Type="vast"/>
                    </ads:PrerollAdvertisement.Source>
                </ads:PrerollAdvertisement>
          </ads:AdSchedulerPlugin.Advertisements>
       </ads:AdSchedulerPlugin>
       <ads:AdHandlerPlugin/>
    </my:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
</my:MediaPlayer>
```

I have tried many ways but not being able to do so. Please suggest any solution to this with complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer to this question. Not an actual solution because as a developer, we do not have the authority to make changes to the look of the advertisement. It's in the hand to Ad service providers only to change the view of the Advertisement.